# Finding limit without L'Hopital's rule of a rational trigonometric expression

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having trouble evaluating the limit below, without L'Hopital's rule of a rational trigonometric expression.

I've tried applying a number of trigonometric limits, but keep coming up blank

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(3x)}{1-\cos(2x)} $$

Comment: Which standard limits do you know for trig functions? What have you tried so far?

Comment: $ sin^2(3x) = 1-cos(3x) $/ $cos(2x)= 1-2sin^2(x)$ /$sin^2x = \frac{1-cos2x}{2}$ My intuition is trying to push me toward the lim x->0 $ \frac{sin(cx)}{sin(bx)} = \frac {c}{b}$ (I hope mathjax works in comments)

Comment: You can do it using Taylor series
$$\sin(x) \approx x \text{ and } \cos(x) \approx 1-\frac 12 x^2$$

Comment: You should include what you have tried in the question.

Comment: Let try with $$ \frac{\sin^2(3x)}{1-\cos(2x)}= \frac{\sin^2(3x)}{(3x)^2} \frac{(2x)^2}{1-\cos(2x)}\frac{(3x)^2}{(2x)^2}$$

Comment: Comment above makes sense to me, except I still can't evaluate the limit of $ \frac {(2x)^2}{1-cos(2x)}$

Comment: @SnakeyB FYI, from the Wikipedia article's section [Multiple-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae), we have $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta) \;\; \to \;\; 1 - \cos(2\theta) = 2\sin^2(\theta)$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You know, john, I know this identity, and had tried to apply it before, but was doing it incorrectly. (I didn't distribute the negative correctly). It seems so simple now. Thanks a million.

Comment: @SnakeyB Are you allowed to use trigonometric identities?

Comment: You can avoid applying the limit $\sin t/t$ by using ${\sin 3x\over \sin x}=2\cos^2x+\cos 2x.$